# Can't call script from script with JQuery in GAS

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, google-apps

I'm having some difficulty getting a script to execute.  I am new to HTML and JQuery.

Using Google Sheets and Google Apps Scripts:

I have 3 files in question:

```
'sidebar.html'
'popup.html'
'scriptsJS.html'
```

Scripts for both 'sidebar' and 'popup' are all in 'scriptsJS'.

The button "#btnRefreshData" is bound to a button in 'sidebar'; this button, and associated scripts work as expected.

I am trying to trigger this same button from another script that is bound to different buttin in 'popup.html', but the call is ignored.

The script below is in 'scriptsJS.html', and is bound to a button in 'popup.html':

```
$( '#btnOpenSelectedItem' ).click(function() {

    this.disabled = true;
    var item = $( "#resultsList" ).find(':selected').val();  

    google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(
          function(msg, element) {
            element.disabled = false;
            doThis(); 
            google.script.host.close();
            })   

        .withFailureHandler(
          function(msg, element) {
            showStatus(msg, 'error');
            element.disabled = false;
          })

        .withUserObject(this)

        .openSelectedItem(item);
  });
```

The script above executes correctly; my data loads, then it calls 'doThis':

```
function doThis () {
     alert ('do this called');
     $( "#btnRefreshData" ).trigger( "click" );  //<-- ignored
};
```

The script above displays an alert successfully (for testing), then attempts to trigger #btnRefreshData. #btnRefreshData is bound to 'sidebar.html', and causes the data in the sidebar to re-populate.

Again, all these scripts are in the same file, but when I call #btnRefreshData (bound to 'sidebar.html) from 'popup.html', it is ignored.

I'm hoping to find a way to trigger this event.  Thank you for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

I will guess that this is an event delegation issue, how are you binding the click handler for `#btnRefreshData`? If You are not delegating it, try to delegate it as follows:

```
 $( "#btnRefreshData" ).on( "click", function() {} ); //My guess on how you are binding it.

 $( document ).on( "click", "#btnRefreshData", function() {} ); //Delegating the event.
```

Comment: Thank you, taxicala... unfortunately, I couldn't get that to work.  On loading,  $( document ).ready(function() {    $( "#btnRefreshData" ).trigger( "click" );    }); failed to trigger this button's click event after I changed it to the 'delegation' style binding.  Thanks for the feedback, though... I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Apps script uses caja to compile the code. For design some of the options you can get on normal javascript are disabled and triggering click programatically is one of them. This is why the code you mentioned is ignored. 
In this case it would be better to call the methods that are executed when clicking the button "#btnRefreshData" inside your doThis method.

Here you can find a little bit of explanation on that: https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/issues/detail?id=1404
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions#restrictions_in_native_and_emulated_mode

Comment: Thanks Gerardo.  That sounds perfect, so I moved all my methods into doThis, but no luck.  The methods that are called read values from elements in the sidebar.html.  When sidebar.html calls doThis, it works fine, but when popup.html calls doThis, the methods fail.  I was able to intercept a failure handler, which returned "NetworkError: Connection failure due to HTTP 0".  I think that the popup.html can't utilize element bindings on the sidebar.html page?